# Streaming big files (pdf) with springboot webflux & angular

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot, pdf, spring-webflux

I've been stuck for several days.
I would like to be able to stream PDF files with many pages.
For the moment, it works for big files with a number of pages less than thousands.

Here is my service side backend (My controller is just a call to this function)

```
public HashMap<String, Long> getRanges(HttpHeaders headers, long size){
    List<HttpRange> rangeHeader = headers.getRange();
    Long start;
    Long end;
    Long contentLength;
    HashMap<String, Long> ranges = new HashMap<>();
    ranges.put("size", size);

    if (!rangeHeader.isEmpty()) {
        start = Long.parseLong(String.valueOf(rangeHeader.get(0).getRangeStart(size)));
        ranges.put("start", start);
        end = size - 1;

        if (rangeHeader.get(0).getRangeEnd(size) > 0) {
            end = Long.parseLong(String.valueOf(rangeHeader.get(0).getRangeEnd(size)));
        }

        ranges.put("end", end);

        contentLength = end - start+1;

        ranges.put("contentLength", contentLength);

    } else {
        ranges.put("start", 0L);
        ranges.put("end", size-1);
        ranges.put("contentLength", size);

    }

    return ranges;
}

public Mono<ResponseEntity<Resource>> getStreaming(String path, HttpHeaders headers) {
    return Mono.fromCallable(() -> {
        try {

            MinioClient minioClient = MinioClient.builder()
                    .endpoint("http://127.0.0.1:9000")
                    .credentials("admin", "password1")
                    .build();

            long size = minioClient.statObject(
                    StatObjectArgs.builder()
                            .bucket("test")
                            .object(path)
                            .build()
            ).size();

            String typeFormat = minioClient.statObject(
                    StatObjectArgs.builder()
                            .bucket("test")
                            .object(path)
                            .build()
            ).contentType();

            GetObjectArgs.Builder argsBuilder = GetObjectArgs
                    .builder()
                    .bucket("test")
                    .object(path);


            HashMap<String, Long> ranges = getRanges(headers, size);

            InputStream obj = minioClient.getObject(argsBuilder
                    .offset(ranges.get("start"))
                    .length(ranges.get("contentLength"))
                    .build());

            InputStreamResource resource = new InputStreamResource(obj);

            HttpHeaders headers1 = new HttpHeaders();

            headers1.set("Accept-Ranges", "bytes");

            headers1.setContentLength(ranges.get("contentLength"));
            headers1.set("Content-Range", "bytes " + ranges.get("start") + "-" + ranges.get("end") + "/" + ranges.get("size"));

            if(!headers.getRange().isEmpty()){

                return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.PARTIAL_CONTENT)
                        .contentType(MediaType.valueOf(typeFormat))
                        .headers(headers1)
                        .body(resource);
            }else {
                return ResponseEntity.ok()
                        .contentType(MediaType.valueOf(typeFormat))
                        .headers(headers1)
                        .body(resource);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    });
}
```

Front-end side I make a very simple call with ngx-pdf-viewer
`<ngx-pdf-viewer [src]="'/service?path=pdf/test_262MB.pdf'"></ngx-pdf-viewer>`

I expect to be able to stream large PDFs

UPDATE :
After several tests I managed to stream PDF files of 226Mb (only 304 pages) and 453Mb (only 608 pages). I concluded that it depends on the number of pages. When I test with some files with big number of pages, I have to download all the content for the viewer to start displaying it. But for others, the viewer only needs a small part to display it. Example on my 226Mb file, the viewer downloads 32Mb and begins to display the PDF. And I can jump between pages, and the content downloads with each page jump. Same for the 453Mb, the viewer downloads 61Mb to start the display.

If anyone knows why some files are required to be fully downloaded?
Thank you

Comment: Maybe I don't understand how you want to do that, but I don't see how you split the `resource` in parts

Comment: @IgorArtamonov No need to split resource in part when using ngx-pdf-viewer it's automatic.

Comment: I'm talking about the backend part, are you sure that only the requested slice of the  `resource` is read into memory?

Comment: @IgorArtamonov I modified the code by implementing MinIO which allows to store data remotely and allows to retrieve slices of the resource (offset/length). When I use this code, I receive a lot of client requests in partial content and the streaming is not functional (for large files). The resource is waiting for the end of the download to be displayed.